# "Крайне настороженно" или "крайне насторожено"?

Tags: орфография, удвоенные-буквы

"Крайне настороженно" или "крайне насторожено"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Относился как? крайне настороженно- наречие, образованное от прилагательного настороженный.
Общество каково? крайне насторожено - краткое причастие от глагола насторожить(внимание).

Answer (score 4):

Надо писать НН. Наречие образовано от прилагательного с двумя НН.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, слово "настороженно" является наречием, образованным от прилагательного "настороженное" или кратким прилагательным от соответствующей полной формы. "Общество крайне настороженно" - здесь это не краткое причастие, а прилагательное.

Comment: Вы отрицаете существование причастия? А оно есть  http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%ED%E0%F1%F2%EE%F0%EE%E6%E5%ED%ED%FB%E9
Общество, которое насторожилось - настороженное

Comment: относиться как?-насторожеННо